# Exchange plist data between 2 iPad using iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, icloud

Suppose I have one app called "AppBuddy" on the AppStore.

Now If I download AppBuddy on one iPad, add one user profile in it, save data into `plist` and sync that `plist` to iCloud.

Now I download AppBuddy on 2nd iPad using same AppleID. Can I get that `plist` from iCloud server and show that user profile on my iPad ?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with some conditions

1. the iCloud id on both devices is the same and the user is logged in to iCloud on both devices. iTunes accounts used to purchase apps can be different from iCloud sync account.
2. the app implements syncing data using iCloud

If you need help on how to support iCloud in apps, [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/icloud-programming-ios-intro-tutorial/) will help.